Missing hotel data in some request
I was trying the API and using the production keys to have full access to the data and if I try with both options of Hotel List (by city or by geocode) I get the same results which doesn't include all the hotels in the zone
For example in Benidorm Spain (which doesn't have Airport so the most close one is Alicant -> ALC IATA) when I was using this I was putting a radius of 80km to inlcude Benidorm city. But to be more accurate I started using geocode but ending up with the same results
This was my request with geocode:
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-geocode?latitude=38.5400&longitude=-0.1300&radius=10&radiusUnit=KM&hotelSource=ALL
I end up with this ones:
BARCELO BENIDORM BEACH
MERCURE BENIDORM
INNSIDE COSTABLANCA
SOL PELICANOS OCAS
HALLEY HOTEL & APARTMENTS AFF BY MELIA
MELIA BENIDORM
MELIA VILLAITANA
THE LEVEL AT MELIA VILLAITANA
B&B HOTEL FINESTRAT
ASIA GARDENS HOTEL
BARCELO LA NUCIA HILLS
BARCELO LA NUCIA PALMS
SHA WELLNESS
I need the result to inlcude more hotels from Benidorm like for example:
-Port Vista Oro

Fleming Playa Poniente
Marconi
Oasis Plaza
Internacional

All and more hotels are not included in the result no matter the parameters used in the request, but if I use the get hotel by name, then the callback is successfull, example of the URL:
https://api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotel?keyword=Marconi&subType=HOTEL_LEISURE&countryCode=ES&lang=EN&max=20
With the above request I can get the details of the hotel and even the HotelId which is AEALCAJZ. So far all good, but the problem is that if I want to check for hotel prices of this Hotel or other hotels which doesn't appear in the geocode Request I get the response of:
"errors": [
{
"code": 3237,
"detail": "Property codes not found in system",
"status": 400,
"title": "PROPERTY CODE NOT FOUND IN SYSTEM"
}
]
Which only happens with these hotels in particulary because if use an HotelId from the geocode response like for example:
"data": [
{
"chainCode": "HA",
"iataCode": "ALC",
"dupeId": 700076211,
"name": "ARECA HOTEL-TORRELLANO",
"hotelId": "HAALCARE",
"geoCode": {
"latitude": 38.29379,
"longitude": -0.58639
},
"address": {
"countryCode": "ES"
},
"distance": {
"value": 2.79,
"unit": "KM"
},
"lastUpdate": "2023-06-15T10:28:16"
},
Then the offer request works fine, any help to achieve the full data of hotels in benidorm or cases like this? Thanks in advance and have a great day
All the tries were described in the previous step

Why are you adding property code to get more hotels.  This is not the issue.  Go back to original request.  Remove property code. Looks like issue is with radius or distance.  I would remove radius and use only distance.

Hi @jdweng yes I tried a lot of combinations before publishing the question here, like removing the parameters to check if there was something not working properly in the request because of that.
I also tried this in both type of requests (geocode and by city)

Code 3237 is airlines (https://docs.fiserv.dev/public/docs/merchant-category-codes).  You Are getting http error 400 which means the request is not valid.  Something is wrong with the combination of parameters that you are using in the request.  Parameters are after the question mark and are separated by ampersand,

Exactly, 400 is bad request but the details is related to the property codes not found, the error I think is because the Hotel Id is invalid in this request.
But the Hotel Id is the one used in the response of the request by name which in the case of Hotel "Marconi" the id is AEALCAJZ. I think the problem is related to this hotel only appearing in the request by name and not in the geocode request. If I use an hotel id in one of the response of geocode, it works perfectly. So seems that some request doesn't return all the hotels or the offer request doesn't include all the hotel ids

Does request work in a Webbrowser?  How about with Postman?  Your link says error is "Authorization Header".  See https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/developer-guides/API-Keys/authorization/  The cookie/token may be expired.  The error could be the cookie is being used from a different request and causing the failure.  Try getting a cookie before each request and see if you still get error.

Yeah sadly each token has a duration of 1 hour or a little more but I was using a conection from unity engine to throw the requests but also I tried with the amadeus test api inside of the main website

And to confirm, the request were success in terms of tokens and data, just incomplete and the last request to get the hotel offers to know the prices was failing with the hotel Id's which were only appearing the the request by name request. The other Hotel id's from the geocode request were working perfect with the offers/prices call and were returning the data correctly. I also tried with both API keys, test ones and production ones

If other hotels are working correctly, then the hotels not working are storing data differently (or not storing the data you want).  Best way of solving is to dump all the data from a hotel that doesn't give the data you want.  See what fields the hotel has loaded into the database.

The not working hotels seems to have all the data saved compare to the working hotels in the response of GetHotelByName request but it's not working for the prices. Looks like some hotels are not linked with the offers/prices in the database and its returning wrong hotel id for these cases. I also sent this in the oficial discord of Amadeus just in case it's a known issue

Wrong hotel id means it is returning airlines?  Is code a string or a number?  What type of number (short, intgeger, long)?

Okey so I made a Google sheet to explain myselft better, here are the screenshots for each request and response:
Request 01 GetToken
Request 02 Get list of Hotels based on latitude and longitude
Request 03 Get Hotel by name
[Request 04]https://ibb.co/4Pfm5Kz) Get Hotel offers/prices using hotelid from GetHotelByName = "Marconi" response
Request 05 Get hotel offers /prices using HotelId from GetHotelsByCity response

So the problem isn't related to the airlines, it's with the Hotel API, Amadeus has 2 API's for the Hotels, 1) Hotel List and 2) Hotel Search, the first one is for listing like the request to search hotels by city or search hotels by hotelid. The second one is for offers/prices once you have the HotelId. The issue comes when after getting the hotelid from the GetHotelByName request and putting it in the GetHotelOffers request I end upt getting an error saying the hotelid doesn't exist when it should be because the API of Hotel List is returning it. So seems to not be synced all the hotel's ids?

Here is the API reference : https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotels/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference

Yeap that is the API used in the last 2 request from above (request  04 and request 05). The request 05 is working as expected and in the screenshot is all the data returned since the HotelId used seems to be included in their side but if I use the hotel id from the hotel name "Marconi" I end up with an error saying it doesn't exist, but its there in others responses from others requets
